# How to structure nested categories in django models

Tags: python, django, database, orm, data-modeling

I am developing a online shopping cart project, and in product-catalog-app I am little bit stumbled upon how to structure categories, for example, the following sequence: ***MEN-> FOOTWEAR-> SPORTS SHOES -> SOME BRAND (NIKE)-> ACTUAL PRODUCT***. As you can see the depth is 5. Is it a good design to make sub sub sub... categories inside each level

```
class Category:
   pass

class SubCategory:
   category=models.ForeignKey(Category,...)
   ...

class SubSubCategory:
   category=models.ForeignKey(SubCategory,...)
   ...

class BrandOrSmthEle:
   category=models.ForeignKey(SubSubCategory,...)
   ...

class Product:
   category=models.ForeignKey(BrandOrSmthEle,...)
   ...
```

Comment: How about one `Category` model with a `self` reference to its parent if it is a subcategory?

Comment: @KlausD. Can you please elaborate your statement a little a bit with some examples?

Comment: Well, have a class with the attribute `parent` which is a foreign key for `'self'` and allows `None`.

Comment: You can look at https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt and https://github.com/django-treebeard/django-treebeard. Packages for creating efficient tree implementations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a suggestion, you could think of more efficient way like,

```
class Gender(Model):
    #male/female
    .....

class Genre(Model):
    #casual/sports/party
    ......

class Type(Model):
    #footwear/clothes/hats
    ......

class Brand(Model):
    #Nike/Adidas/Puma
    .....

class Product(Model):
    gender = ForeignKey(Gender)
    genre = ForeignKey(Genre)
    type = ForeignKey(Type)
    brand = ForeignKey(Brand)
    ......
```

You could avoid the nested architecture by employing this hierarchy.

Comment: wow, really good suggestion, how I could have not thought about this :), really simple